# uploading images with Limitation

Tags: php, html

Hello! I have file upload that **I want to upload only six images not less not more only six images with the PNG and JPG types i have written the below code.**

But that is giving this below error please some one check my code and find the mistakes.

> "Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 21
>       Your Images Must Be JPG OR PNG And equal to six images
>       Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 21
>       Your Images Must Be JPG OR PNG And equal to six images"

```
HTML Code:

<form name="myWebForm" action="hiddenprocess.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="Upload_Property_Images[]" multiple="multiple"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload_Images" style="cursor:pointer;"/>

</form>

   Here is the PHP FILE UPLOAD CODE:

<?php

$imagename = $_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']['name'];
$imagetype = $_FILES["Upload_Property_Images"]['type'];


    if (empty($imagename))
    {
        echo 'You have\'nt Entered Value for upload field';
        exit(); 
    }

    else

    {

$whitelist = array(".jpg",".png");
                  foreach ($whitelist as $item)
                    {
                       if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $imagename) && count($imagename ==6))
                          {

                           //code for uploading goes in here

                          }
                          else
                          {
                               echo 'Your Images Must Be 
                               -JPG OR PNG
                               -Only six images allowed';

                          }
                    }

    }



?>
```

Comment: your hint is already the error shown.

Comment: Obviously you are giving the wrong parameters for preg_match(). The second parameter(after the comma) should be a string, not an array.

Comment: because `$imagename` is array, when you upload multiple images it becomes array, for single image this is true. You should use `for loop` for checking with names of each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
// Process files one by one
foreach($_FILES as $file) {

 // Allowed file types
 $whitelist = array("jpg","png");

  // Match uploaded file extension
  if ( in_array(end(explode('.', $file['Upload_Property_Images']['name'])), $whitelist ) {

    // Count total uploads
    if (count($_FILES['Upload_Property_Images']) == 6) {
       // Code here
    } else {
       // Count error 
    }
  } else {
       // File extension error 
  }
}
```

Comment: where i should spacify if the conditions are not fulfilled i mean the  error massage

Comment: Now i got this error "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\hiddenprocess.php on line 21"